# Only Satellite mode in android app map view

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-api

By default map view gives standard mode, when `mapView.setSattelite(true)` the map view turn to hybrid mode of satellite and standard, i want to display only satellite mode in my map view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..:

Insert this check at onCreate Method.

```
if(!mapView.isSatelliteView())
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
```

Hope this'll help.
Cheers

Comment: is guess its isSatellite instead of isSatelliteView, still i m having hybrid mode

Comment: This is what I do in my code regarding map view, i am having hybrid view, i want to display only satellite view with no countries or borders mentioned:                                if(!mapView.isSatellite())
            mapView.setSatellite(true);                                            float lat = 30.248391f;//39.295765945f;
        float lng = 67.001495f;
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6));
        mc = mapView.getController();
        mc.animateTo(point);
        mc.setZoom(5);